# Preventing key event delay

Tags: javascript, createjs

I am working with `createjs`. My goal is to move a texture while one of the WASD keys is down with one condition, the texture can be moved only in one direction at once. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
//I use this to prevent simultaneous key events
var currentKeyCode = null; 

//Assign event listener
window.addEventListener("keydown", handleMovement, false); 
window.addEventListener("keyup", setMovementFlag, false);


//This will make the hero move 
//only if no other key is down or if it is the same key as in last event
function handleMovement(event) {
    if (!currentKeyCode || currentKeyCode == event.keyCode) {
        currentKeyCode = event.keyCode;
        hero.Move(event);
    }
}

//Here the keyCode flag is set to null as no key is currently being pressed
function setMovementFlag(event) {
    currentKeyCode = null;
}

//And finally this is the code that moves the "texture" based on the event
Hero.prototype.Move = function (event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 65: // A down, move left
            var nextPositionX = this.texture.x - this.speed;

            this.facingDirection = 'left';

            if (!this.PredictCollision(new Vector2(nextPositionX, this.texture.y))) {
                this.texture.x -= this.speed;
            }
            break;
        case 68: // D down, move right
            var nextPositionX = this.texture.x + this.speed;

            this.facingDirection = 'right';

            if (!this.PredictCollision(new Vector2(nextPositionX, this.texture.y))) {
                this.texture.x += this.speed;
            }
            break;
        case 83: //S down, move down
            var nextPositionY = this.texture.y + this.speed;

            this.facingDirection = 'down';

            if (!this.PredictCollision(new Vector2(this.texture.x, nextPositionY))) {
                this.texture.y += this.speed;
            }
            break;
        case 87: //W down, move up
            var nextPositionY = this.texture.y - this.speed;

            this.facingDirection = 'up';

            if (!this.PredictCollision(new Vector2(this.texture.x, nextPositionY))) {
                this.texture.y -= this.speed;
            }
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

The problem is whenever I hold down a key the texture moves a bit, then it seems to freeze for a moment until it moves on. 
I am not sure if the problem lies within my implementation or how events are handled in JavaScript. But this behaviour makes the movement to appear somehow stuttering.